# How properly use MSG_host_set_property_value() in SimGrid?

Tags: properties, platform, simgrid

There is one host:

```
<host id="Worker1" speed="1Mf" core="101"/>
```

Only one process deploys on this host:

```
<process host="Worker1" function="worker"/>
```

The worker function is below:

```
int worker(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MSG_host_set_property_value(MSG_host_self(), "activeCore", "0", xbt_free_f);
    MSG_task_execute(MSG_task_create("kot", 10e6, 0, NULL));
    XBT_INFO("I've executed some stuff and changed my value");
    MSG_host_set_property_value(MSG_host_self(), "activeCore", "1", xbt_free_f);
    return 0;
}
```

When I use `MSG_host_set_property_value` for the second time the `Segmentation fault` raises.

How to avoid it?

I know that the reason in `xbt_free_f`. If I change it to `NULL` simulation will work fine. But I fear that will impact on productivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at examples/msg/platform-properties/platform-properties.c you should write 
MSG_host_set_property_value(MSG_host_self(), "activeCore", **xbt_strdup("0")**, xbt_free_f);

and

MSG_host_set_property_value(MSG_host_self(), "activeCore", **xbt_strdup("1")**, xbt_free_f);